# Chilli Plant Bugs/Brown-Purple Staining

Tags: indoors, diseases, chili, bugs, pests

I have an indoor jalapeno, cayenne and birds eye chillies which I planted from seed and moved indoors at the end of summer. They have become infested with tiny bugs which live on the bottoms of the leaves mostly (see pic):

[image]

This happened before, and after I sprayed the plants with soapy water they seemed to disappear only to reappear a month later! Any advice on what they are and how to get rid of them would be greatly appreciated!

Also the jalapeno plant has been developing brown/purple patches (see pic):

[image]

I have been using Chilli Focus Plant since last week, and prior to that was using a tomato plant feed that apparently matched chilli requirements quite well.

Comment: The second photo: Is it more of a brown rot, or just a surface purple colour? If the latter it is probably natural. I see it a lot. Fruit will sometimes also gain the same colour - ie. it is genetic.

Comment: Just a surface purple colour. Ah really? Good to know, I thought the bugs had given the plant a disease!

Comment: If the plants grow to large for a kitchen sink and it tap then a shower will do fine. I need to do this at least once per month for my indoor peppers (jalapeno, habaneros and scotch bonnet). Soapy water alone was inadequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are aphids.  An insecticidal soap (available at the garden center) should be effective in controlling them. You will probably have to apply it often, one application would not be expected to control them forever.

Another thing you can do depending on how large the plants are is to simply to put the plant in the kitchen sink and use the hose sprayer to physically remove the bugs.  Then use the insecticidal soap after it is dry.